# Kapow Robomaker - Set Named Tag

Tags: tags, named, kapow

i'm a novice on kapow robomaker and maybe someone can help me with named tags.

How shall I configurate the "Set Named Tag" in kapow robomaker if I want to add the specifications "Geschlecht" and "Material Typ" for the frame ?

[html code for the named tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpSDR.png)

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the tag -> Other -> Set as Named Tag

and change the Finder to locate

- Tag Path: .*.div
- Tag Pattern: Geschlecht
- Match against: Text only

Same for the other one.
It is somewhat more complicated if you mean to name the parent div tag.